# Library Project Supporting Eclipse and Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, library-project

I'm working on a library project that provides access to a service. We started the project few months ago and we were supporting Eclipse only (since Android Studio was a prewview edition).

Now that Android Studio has become a "beta" version, and its popularity has increased greatly, we had the intention to support it as welll, but we are facing the problem of how to support both "styles" with the same base (project structure and code).

The library we are building has a UI that forced us to have the library as library project instead of just a simple jar. We have this project working with ANT to build the required files (jars) and packaging everthing in a library project.

Android Studio now introduces the .aar library files, that can also contain UI.

So our problem is finding examples of other library projects containing UI that are also supporting both IDE's. Wondering if someone else have face this same situation.

Is is possible to have a Library Project to support both IDEs? (Eclipse and Android Studio)

Comment: It is definitely possible to have a library project that supports Eclipse and Gradle for Android. Most of my CWAC libraries are set up that way. Android Studio just hung when I tried importing one of those projects, suggesting that my `build.gradle` files and/or Studio need some work...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CommonsWare. When I looked at your projects I realize that we didn't need our project to be "Android Studio compatible". Since we wanted to share the project as an .aar file, I had only to make a build.gradle at the root of my library project and add the gradle folder (containing the gradle wrapper jars).

In this way I can use the console and create a .aar file using "./gradlew aR" command. Now I can distribute the library project for Eclipse users or the .aar file for Android Studio users.

I'm testing the .aar file, and the only problem I have right now is that classes inside a jar file within libs folder inside the .aar file are not recognized, just the classes present inside "classes.jar", but I think I would create another question here in SOF since is not relevant for this question.